# is it possible to generate electricity using phototransistors

Tags: electromagnetism

When the photo transistor is exposed to light it generate electricity, is it possible to increase the output by increasing the gain and store the electricty ?

Comment: Phototransistor is not generating electricity.

Comment: So if you feed the generated electricity back into the transistor's base to increase the gain you then generate more electricity which you can feed back into the base to increase the gain to generate more electricity to .... ;)

Comment: Well you can generate some power from a phototransistor, or a photodiode or even a diode alone, but expect maybe 100nW per part in full direct sunlight.

Answer (score 2):

**No**

A phototransitor does not generate electricity.  It is more like a switch which is turned on by light.  So when a phototransistor is providing power to a circuit, it is taking that power from the power rail it is connected to.

There is another silicon component which *does* generate power when light falls on it.  It's called a solar cell.  If you want to store the energy from a solar cell for later use, you can use a capacitor (for short term storage) or a rechargeable battery (for longer time periods).

Comment: The base current in a phototransistor *is* generated by light. The base-collector junction is operates in photovoltaic mode, and the generated base current is then amplified by the transistor itself.

Comment: True, perhaps I have oversimplified.  The power available from the tiny area of the pn junction is minuscule though, especially when compared to the power the transistor can switch.

Answer (score 2):

They make three terminal photo-transistors, and if you just hook-up the base and emitter you have a photo-diode... so you can generate electricity from some photo-transistors.  (When used as a photo-diode.)

Answer (score 1):

All semiconductors can generate current from light. Even old UV erased memory chips could be converted into a poor quality pixel matrix camera.

The best  common Silicon photo diodes are about 0.5 mA/mW of solar radiation but considering a 1mm2 chip size compared to 1kW/m2 of solar power you only get one milliwatt of power per square millimetre in bright sun.

The current gain in transistors comes at cost of rise in impedance or lower voltage, so the V*I power output can never exceed the input current and is usually much less from conduction losses.

But in Phototransistors, the output current must be an externally DC supply and the transistor only becomes an "active" load to switch or vary current and create a voltage modulated by solar input.

> So in conclusion a  photo transistor cannot supply any power. Zero, nada , nothing, whereas a photo diode can, such as in a large solar diode arrays.

Transistor collectors are modelled as **current sinks** not current sources with high impedance like photodiodes which **are** current sources.

This is an important distinction to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Phototransistor gain is not a "free lunch." While the base current is photogenerated, the amplified collector current is sourced from the biasing supply, so there's no magical power appearing from nowhere.

In principle, if you had a three-terminal phototransistor (with a base connection) and left the collector disconnected, you'd have a photodiode. If you connected the emitter to ground you would be able to extract a small current at around 0.7V from the base (photovoltaic mode). It would not be particularly efficient, as photodiodes have small active areas are not optimized for power production. What you want for this is a conventional solar cell.

Answer (score 0):

Your first premise is incorrect. A photo-transistor does NOT "generate electricity".  Furthermore "gain" consumes power, so the second premise is incorrect as well.